# How to switch an android view based on a condition

Tags: android, view

I am creating an Android application that will mainly consists of ListViews in each activity. What I hope to achieve is a mechanism that will check to see if network connectivity is present and if so then then the data should be retrieved and supplied to the ListView. If there's no data present or the internet connection is unavailable then a seperate view should be loaded.

Which way is most efficient do to this. So far I have seen answers about using a ViewSwitcher or Viewflipper but I am not sure that's the right approach. Should I use fragments and then load a particular fragment based on the condition that was met? I just need some advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you need to know about connectivity in real time or at certain times while your app runs?

Comment: I will have a function in each activity that checks for data and loads the list view adapter with that data. That's where I will check to see if internet is present or not. That function will be called when the activity is first created.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I've recently been studying that part of the API, but I'd look into a BoundService for that.  This way, all of your Activities can bind to it and get the data it holds from doing that work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just swapping the adapter? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877151/is-it-okay-to-change-a-listviews-adapter-dynamically) question might be of some use to you.

I guess you might add some kind of factory method that will decide what adapter to instantiate depending on connectivity availability. Thus you will control both the data to be used and the appearance of list entries (I assume you will be using some custom extension of one of the existing adapters).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is going to be to use the [`emptyView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) that's provided as part of the `AdapterView` base class. You just set the adapter as per usual, but if no data is retrieved (i.e. your adapter's data source is empty) you will show the empty view in place of the list. This empty view can be anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ivan says you should consider setting adapters in a dinamic way.

And about the fragments thing, only consider using independent fragments (or ListFragments) for this if you are going to re-use that fragments in other activities to avoid code duplication.