# Changing the adapter of a ListView with Button click - GUI glitch

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a ListView and two buttons above it. The contents of the ListView changes depending on which button is clicked. To do this, I have two BaseAdapters. ListView.SetAdapter() is called when the user clicks a button. I am getting a GUI glitch when I change adapter; attached are screen shots of the problem.
@Bondax briefly mentions the problem in this post: [Is it okay to change a ListView's adapter dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877151/is-it-okay-to-change-a-listviews-adapter-dynamically) . But I have found no solution. Code attached for onCreate of fragment containing ListView and of the two adapters. Also, if it's relevant, each distinct row in the listview is ConstraintLayout. Any and all help would be appreciated! :)
Recorded tracks button First time loads fine.
[image]

Then I click All Time Button, which sets new adapter. GUI glitch here.

[image]

Then I click Recorded tracks again and it too, bugs out.

[image]

CODE:
onCreate of fragment that contains listview

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);

        trackStatsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listOfTracksListView);
        trackStatsListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ImageButton recordedTracksButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.recordedTracksButton);
        ImageButton allTimeBestButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.allTimeBestButton);

        //All Time stats clicked
    allTimeBestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recordedTracksClicked = false;
            trackStatsListView.setAdapter(null);

            final allTimeBestAdapter allTimeBestAdapter = new allTimeBestAdapter(getActivity());

            trackStatsListView.setAdapter(allTimeBestAdapter);
        }
    });

    //Recorded Tracks clicked (click by default when Fragment loads up)
    recordedTracksButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recordedTracksClicked = true;

            SkiCompanionDatabase db = new SkiCompanionDatabase(getActivity());

            PopulateTrack populateTrack;

            //TODO: add in location awareness
            //populating data for each track
            listOfTracks = new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor trackIDPosition = db.getAllTrackIDs();
            trackIDPosition.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < db.numberOfTracks(); i++) {
                currentID = trackIDPosition.getLong(trackIDPosition.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_TRACK_DESC_ID));
                populateTrack = new PopulateTrack(getActivity(), currentID);
                listOfTracks.add(new TrackDescription(currentID, db.getNameFromTrackID(currentID), db.getDateFromTrackID(currentID), "Whistler", populateTrack.totalDuration(), populateTrack.totalDistance()));
                trackIDPosition.moveToNext();
            }

            trackStatsListView.setAdapter(null);

            final StatsAdapter statsAdapter = new StatsAdapter(getActivity(), listOfTracks);

            //setting an adapter to put list data into the ListView
            trackStatsListView.setAdapter(statsAdapter);


            //setting the onClick for each element in the list - will replace current fragment with new fragment
            trackStatsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (recordedTracksClicked) {
                        //getting the ID of the track selected
                        Bundle itemClicked = new Bundle();
                        itemClicked.putLong("trackID", listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getId());

                        //adding the id as an extra (argument) for the next fragment
                        Fragment trackStatsFragment = new TrackStatsFragment();
                        trackStatsFragment.setArguments(itemClicked);

                        android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

                        //replacing fragment, we push to backStack so that StatsFragment is still navigable with the back button
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, trackStatsFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    recordedTracksButton.callOnClick();

    return view;
}
```

AllTimeAdapter and RecordedTrackAdapter:

```
//helper class to populate ListView
    class StatsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<TrackDescription> listOfTracks;
        private Context context;

        //Constructor
        StatsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TrackDescription> listOfTracks) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listOfTracks = listOfTracks;
        }

        //total number elements in list
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listOfTracks.size();
        }

        //returns the object of an item at index i in ListView
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return listOfTracks.get(i);
        }

        //used for returning index of Database element
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        //method which populates ListView. The Row design is specified in list_of_tracks_row.xml
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //ViewHolder is a kind of cache and is a public helper class. When an object is scrolled outside of view
            //(into recycler), its data is store in ViewHolder, so that it can be quickly loaded when the user scrolls over it again.
            ViewHolder viewHolder;


            if (view == null) {
                //inflating layout list_of_tracks_row.XML on each iteration
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_tracks_row, viewGroup, false);

                //populating ViewHolder object
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackName);
                viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackDate);
                viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackLocation);
                viewHolder.tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackDuration);
                viewHolder.tv5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackDistance);

                //associating current view with the relevant ViewHolder
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }


            //setting the text of the TextViews in the row
            //newest to oldest
            viewHolder.tv1.setText(listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getName());
            viewHolder.tv2.setText(listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getDate());
            viewHolder.tv3.setText(listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getLocation());
            viewHolder.tv4.setText(millisToHMS(listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getDuration()));
            viewHolder.tv5.setText(String.valueOf((int) listOfTracks.get(listOfTracks.size() - 1 - i).getDistance()) + "m");

            //TODO: to speed up fragment load time, use distance and duration stored in database.
//            viewHolder.tv5.setText(String.valueOf((int) skiCompanionDatabase.getDistanceFromTrackID(30)) + "m");


            return view;
        }
    }

    class allTimeBestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private AppPreferences appPreferences;

        public allTimeBestAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.appPreferences = new AppPreferences(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //number of different types in list, ie. speed, altitude...
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 8;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //ViewHolder is a kind of cache and is a public helper class. When an object is scrolled outside of view
            //(into recycler), its data is store in ViewHolder, so that it can be quickly loaded when the user scrolls over it again.
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;

            //i is the current row number. Switch statement determines the layout to be inflated depending on the row number
            //row 0: speed: track_list_row_speed , row 1: altitude: track_list_row_altitude , etc...
            switch (i) {
                /*      DURATION      */
                case 0:
                    if (view == null) {
                        //inflating layout specific to the row 1, ie. track_list_row_speed
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_duration, viewGroup, false);

                        //populating ViewHolder object
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListTotalDuration);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListAscentDuration);
                        viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListDescentDuration);

                        //associating current view with the relevant ViewHolder
                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(millisToHMS(appPreferences.getAllTimeTotalDuration()));
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(millisToHMS(appPreferences.getAllTimeAscentDuration()));
                    viewHolder.tv3.setText(millisToHMS(appPreferences.getAllTimeDescentDuration()));

//                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(millisToHMS(track.getTotalDuration()));
//                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(millisToHMS(track.getAscentDuration()));
//                    viewHolder.tv3.setText(millisToHMS(track.getDescentDuration()));
                    break;
                /*      DISTANCE      */
                case 1:
                    if (view == null) {
                        //inflating layout specific to the row 1, ie. track_list_row_speed
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_distance, viewGroup, false);

                        //populating ViewHolder object
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListTotalDistance);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListAscentDistance);
                        viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListDescentDistance);

                        //associating current view with the relevant ViewHolder
                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeTotalDistance()) + 'm');
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeAscentDistance()) + 'm');
                    viewHolder.tv3.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeDescentDistance()) + 'm');
                    break;
                /*      SPEED      */
                case 2:
                    if (view == null) {
                        //inflating layout specific to the row 1, ie. track_list_row_speed
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_speed, viewGroup, false);

                        //populating ViewHolder object
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListTopSpeed);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListAvgSpeed);

                        //associating current view with the relevant ViewHolder
                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    //multiplying by 18/5 converts m/s to km/h
                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(String.valueOf(appPreferences.getAllTimeTopSpeed() * (18 / 5)).substring(0, String.valueOf(appPreferences.getAllTimeTopSpeed() * (18 / 5)).indexOf('.') + 2) + "km/h");
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf(appPreferences.getAllTimeAvgSpeed() * (18 / 5)).substring(0, String.valueOf(appPreferences.getAllTimeAvgSpeed() * (18 / 5)).indexOf('.') + 2) + "km/h");
                    break;
                /*      PACE      */
                case 3:
                    if (view == null) {
                        //inflating layout specific to the row 1, ie. track_list_row_speed
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_pace, viewGroup, false);

                        //populating ViewHolder object
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListBestPace);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListAvgPace);

                        //associating current view with the relevant ViewHolder
                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    //multiplying by 18/5 converts m/s to km/h
                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(secondsToMS(appPreferences.getAllTimeBestPace()));
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(secondsToMS(appPreferences.getAllTimeAvgPace()));

                    break;
                /*      ALTITUDE      */
                case 4:
                    if (view == null) {
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_altitude, viewGroup, false);

                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListMinAltitude);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListMaxAltitude);
                        viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListGainAltitude);
                        viewHolder.tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListLossAltitude);

                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    //setting the text of the TextViews in the row
                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeMinAltitude()) + 'm');
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeMaxAltitude()) + 'm');
                    viewHolder.tv3.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeGainAltitude()) + 'm');
                    viewHolder.tv4.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeLossAltitude()) + 'm');
                    break;
                /*      GRADIENT      */
                case 5:
                    if (view == null) {
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_row_gradient, viewGroup, false);

                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListMaxGradient);
                        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statsListGainGradient);

                        view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    viewHolder.tv1.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeMaxGradient()) + '\u00B0');
                    viewHolder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf((int) appPreferences.getAllTimeAvgGradient()) + '\u00B0');
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: XML CODE:

list_of_track_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Track name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorStatsListTitle"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trackName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trackName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trackName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trackName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trackName"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trackName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trackDate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trackDate"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trackDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trackDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trackDate"
        android:text="Location"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trackDate" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trackLocation"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trackName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/trackLocation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_chevron_right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/trackDistanceDescription"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trackDistanceDescription"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trackDistanceDescription"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trackDistanceDescription"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trackDistanceDescription"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="0.0 km"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/trackDuration"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/trackDuration"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trackDuration" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/trackDurationDescription"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trackDurationDescription"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trackDurationDescription"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trackDurationDescription"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trackDurationDescription"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you add the xml layouts for your items? list_of_tracks_row etc

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far guys, @Ben P. I added XML code above for list_of_tracks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any people in the future with this problem: There is a bug/glitch with the newly developed ConstraintLayout, released 2017. I have switched to RelativeLayout in my custom ListView rows and the world is normal once again.